# What is the Maximum Time we can set using RestRequest.Timeout C#?

Tags: c#, timeout

I want to set 10 min to perform the operation but it seems to wait only for 4 min. Is this the maximum time? Is there any way we can set 10 min wait time?

Here's my example:

```
        RestRequest rr = FormRequest(Method.POST, url);
        rr.Timeout = 600000; // 10 min in millisecond
        rr.AddJsonBody(input);
        return ExecuteRequest(rr);
```

Answer (score 0):

try using Thread.sleep(timelimit)

Comment: "sleep" should start with a capital case